# Prove that, the product space $I^I$ is separable

Tags: general-topology

Prove that, the product space $I^I$ is separable , where $I=[0,1]$

Proof:
$I^I$ is nothing but the space of all functions from $I$ to $I$
with an element of basis is of the form,

$B_n=\{g\in I^I: g(x_i)\in U_i\subset [0,1], i=1(1)n, ~U_i~\text{is an open interval in } [0,1]\}$

Now for, $(x_1,x_2,..,x_n)\in \mathbb{Q}^n$ we corresponds a function $f:I \to I$ as,

$f(x)=x_i,$ if $\frac{i-1}{n}\le x<\frac{i}{n}$ and $f(1)=x_n$

Let, $S$ be the collection of all such functions.
Since, $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{Q}^n$ is countable so is $S.$
Suppose, $U$ is an open set of $I^I$ then there exists a basis $B_k=\{g\in I^I: g(x_i)\in U_i\subset [0,1], i=1(1)k, ~U_i~\text{is an open interval in } [0,1]\}\subset U$

WLOG, we now assume, $x_1<x_2<..<x_k$ and say, $\min_{1\le i\le k-1}(x_{i+1}-x_i)=m.$

Now we take $n$ such that, $\frac{1}{n}<m$ and further choose $y_i\in U_i\cap\mathbb{Q}.$
Then, either $x_i\in [\frac{r_i}{n},\frac{r_i+1}{n})$ for some, $r_i\in \{0,1,..,n-1\}$ with $r_i\ne r_j$ for $i\ne j$ or $x_i=1$

Now,if $x_k=1$ we define,

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} y_i,\text{if}~ x\in [\frac{r_i}{n},\frac{r_i+1}{n}),\\y_k ,x=x_k\\0 ,\text{else}\end{cases}$$

If $x_k\ne 1$ we define,
$f(x)=\begin{cases} y_i,\text{if}~ x\in [\frac{r_i}{n},\frac{r_i+1}{n}),\\0 ,\text{else}\end{cases}$

Then, $f\in S \cap B_k$, hence $\bar{S}=I^I$ and this completes the proof.

Is it correct? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this works. This is the countable case of the [Hewitt-Marczewski-Pondiczery theorem](http://planetmath.org/hewittmarczewskipondiczerytheorem). Hewitt’s original paper can be found [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1946-52-08/S0002-9904-1946-08613-9/). This result itself is [Theorem $16.4$c](http://books.google.com/books?id=-o8xJQ7Ag2cC&pg=PA109#v=onepage&q&f=false) in Willard’s *General Topology*.

Comment: Thank you for the references.

Comment: You’re welcome.